# Arrays getting changed inside irrelevant object

Tags: c#, arrays

For my end of year project I need to develop an image processing and artificial intelligence application.

My image processing is already done, so I'm moving to the AI. However I have a problem here.

I will try to describe the situation here.

For a correct image processing I need an AI that can validate the board through the rules of checkers. So I need to check the current state of the play field with the last known state.

So for this I created an object with the `currentBoard` 2 dimensional array, and a method that validates the raw input of the board with the `currentBoard` (= last known state).

However, when another object -- my image processing object -- is finished with his method, it will change the array `currentBoard` in my AI object.

This is the same for a new array I created inside the main form. I think this happens cause of the heap/stack.

I hope I made my problem clear and understandable. I know I'm not the best in describing situations so please tell me when you don't understand a part completely.

Comment: How does the code look? Perhaps you need to make a deep copy of your `currentBoard`?

Comment: what you want to implement is immutable objects and defensive copying.

Comment: @DarthVader I think i need a mutable object since "currentBoard" of the object needs to be updated, or am i wrong here? And could you explain the defensive copying, i dont understand the term and google didnt really explain alot.

Comment: @DanielFisher Could you give me an example of deep copying? To set my "currenBoard" i use the get/set method.

Comment: @ySomic no u dont need a mutable object. u make them immutable and every time u make a change your class returns a new instance. this was you can control what s being change and what not. for defensive copying look at http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15 this is your problem, might be.

Comment: *Show us the code.* Without the code, we have to make broad generalizations, fallible assumptions, and wild guesses.

Comment: I've read your question a couple of times now and I really don't understand what your question is. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are reference types, so, as you've found, changing the array contents in one place will change it for any other code which holds a reference to the same object.

To avoid changing the array, you should take a deep copy of your 2 dimensional array and work with the copy instead. Note that we have to take a deep copy of both the array and its internal arrays:

```
        int[][] original = {new[] {1,2,3}, new[] {4,5,6}};

        int[][] deepCopy = new int[original.Length][];

        for (int index = 0; index < original.Length; index++)
        {
            var row = original[index];
            int[] rowCopy = new int[row.Length];
            row.CopyTo(rowCopy, 0);

            deepCopy[index] = rowCopy;
        }
```

You can also produce the same result using some simple linq:

```
int[][] deepCopyLinq = original.Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToArray();
```